# Performing an operation over the elements of one collection and iterating over the result to perform some other operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have 2 collections,

```
List<String> domainArr;
List<Person> personArr;
```

I would like to make a minor transformation on each of the elements in the String and then iterate over the personArr to

```
List<String> urlArr = strArr.stream()
    .map(str -> "https://" + strArr)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have a method like

```
List<Person> getPersons(String url){
 /*makes a restful call to the url and gets a List of objects for each URL.*/
}
```

I would like to iterate over each of the urls from urlArr and pass it to the getPersons(url) method and for each of the obtained result (a List), I would like to iterate over the person and perform more operations on the persons like

```
persons.stream()
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .map(Person::getName)
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am hoping to have all the person names here from all the results.

I was wondering how to do this the functional way in Java 8. Any pointers?

Comment: This is somewhat unclear (right now, if I had to guess, I'd say you should look into `flatMap`).  Can you illustrate with a concrete example of what you want to happen here?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `flatMap()`.

Comment: What is the result of `someOtherOperation()`? Or is it just an action? If it is just an action, `strArr.forEach(str -> getPersons("https://" + str).forEach(p -> someOtherOperation(p, str)));` If `someOtherOperation` only requires the person, you could also use `strArr.stream()
    .flatMap(str -> getPersons("https://" + str).stream()) .forEach(p -> someOtherOperation(p))`

Comment: @Holger I have updated the question with what I would be doing with each of the persons.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am expecting to have all the person names in a List<String>. Have updated the question further.

Comment: Then, `flatMap` is the way to go, `strArr.stream() .flatMap(str->getPersons("https://"+str) .stream()) /* your other stream operations: */ .filter(Objects::nonNull) .map(Person::getName) .filter(Objects::nonNull) .collect(Collectors.toList());`…

Comment: @Holger The solution you have provided works. Have accepted ByeBye's solution since I have it as an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to convert your stream of `List<T>` into flat stream of `T`

```
strArr.stream()
    .map(str -> "https://" + strArr)
    .map(url -> getPersons(url))
    .flatMap(persons -> persons.stream())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Person::getName)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I have slightly modified the solution like .map(str -> getPersons("https://" + strArr)). Out of curiosity, how would I return a map of <url, List<names from that url>>

Comment: You should ask another question. (check `Collectors.toMap`)