# Collecting the result of an iteration on one object in to a map with values from another object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This question is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657202/performing-an-operation-over-the-elements-of-one-collection-and-iterating-over-t?noredirect=1#47657202). I have provided all the needed details here.

If I have 2 collections,

```
List<String> domainArr;
List<Person> personArr;
```

I would like to make a minor transformation on each of the elements in the String and then iterate over the personArr to

```
List<String> urlArr = strArr.stream()
    .map(str -> "https://" + strArr)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have a method like

```
List<Person> getPersons(String url){
 /*makes a restful call to the url and gets a List of objects for each URL.*/
}
```

I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657202/performing-an-operation-over-the-elements-of-one-collection-and-iterating-over-t?noredirect=1#47657202) that I can collect the results into a flattened list like

```
strArr.stream()
    .map(str -> getPersons("https://" + str))
    .flatMap(persons -> persons.stream())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Person::getName)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I was wondering how get the result in a Map with key as the domainUrl and Value as a list of names obtained by transforming the result of that particular URL?

Say a map like,

```
URL1 -> [name1, name2]
URL2 -> [name3, name4]
```

Comment: `domainArr` and `strArray` are the same? What types does the map you want to get hold?

Answer (score 4):

For readability, you can define a separate method that extracts the list of names for a URL:

```
List<String> personNames(String url) {
    return getPersons(url).stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)    // why would you return null persons?
            .map(Person::getName)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)    // why would... nevermind! :)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then you can write:

```
strArr.stream()
        .map("https://"::concat)    // Your code here says `.map(str -> "https://" + strArr)`, which I suppose should be `.map(str -> "https://" + str)`
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::personNames));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below, where `resultMap` is what you're looking for:

```
   domainArr.stream()
            .forEach(domain -> {
                String url = "https://" + domain;
                List<Person> persons = getPersons(url);
                Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = persons.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(Person::getName)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> url, Arrays::asList, (a, b) -> {
                            a.addAll(b);
                            return a;
                        }));

            });
```